# Block incoming calls in WP 7

Tags: windows-phone, call, block

I'd like to know if there's any way to block incoming calls or messages in WP 7.x

I've seen some rumours that it's not possible at all, but those information were old-dated.

How about now? Is there any way?

Comment: Are you asking about code, or how to use the phone?

Comment: actually I'm talking about codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically there is no way to intercept or block calls and messages in both Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Yap! I've had the same sad answer at others forums. It's a shame that WP can't do that whereas many others do.